# compiling Audacity 2.0.3

Tags: command-line

Starting from a download of Audacity 2.0.3 tarball, how do I go through the installation procedure. I have no experience of this procedure.

Answer (score 2):

To install Audacity, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:audacity-team/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

Or just click [**Audacity** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/audacity/)

Or if you still want to compile, see [Compiling Audacity For Beginners](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/CompilingAudacityForBeginners)

Answer (score 1):

There is a guide on the Ubuntu Forums that might be of use to you:

Audacity under Trusty Tahr: Building it with FFmpeg
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219907

This contains step by step compiling instructions for the newest version of Audacity and also a method of adding support for FFmpeg (which is missing in Trusty Tahr).